# Unable to initialise UIImage in TableCellView

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, swift3

I am trying to learn Swift so this question might be a little stupid, bear with me please.

I have a function which initialises the properties like this-

```
private func loadSampleMeals(){
    let photo1 = UIImage(named: "meal1")
    let photo2 = UIImage(named: "meal2")
    let photo3 = UIImage(named: "meal3")

    guard let meal1 = Meal(name: "meal1", photo: photo1, rating: 4) else {
        fatalError("Unable to initialize meal1")
    }

    guard let meal2 = Meal(name: "meal2", photo: photo2, rating: 3) else{
        fatalError("Unable to initialize meal2")
    }

    guard let meal3 = Meal(name: "meal3", photo: photo3, rating: 1) else{
        fatalError("Unable to initialize meal3")
    }

    meals += [meal1, meal2, meal3]
}
```

Then I am trying to load them to the table cell like-

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "MealTableViewCell"

    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? MealTableViewCell else {
        fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of MealTableViewCell.")
    }

    let meal = meals[indexPath.row]

    cell.nameLabel.text = meal.name
    cell.photoImageView.image = meal.photo // <- error here
    cell.ratingControl.rating = meal.rating

    return cell
}
```

I get below error when I assign the image property in the above code-

> [UITableViewCellContentView setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0x7fa19ed019a0 2018-05-18 14:12:28.845232+0530
>   FoodTracker[2440:67077] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception
>   'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UITableViewCellContentView
>   setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7fa19ed019a0'

I have added the images and they are in .jpg format with names `meal1`, `meal2` and `meal3`. But don't know what I am doing wrong. Interestingly I have another image- `defaultPhoto` in the assists and if I comment out the line above that throws the error, my code runs fine and the emulator shows `defaultPhoto` image.

Here's how my asset looks like-

[image]

Any help with this please? Let me know if I can add more details.

**Edit:**

My outlets looks like this-

```
class MealTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    //MARK: Properties
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var photoImageView: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var ratingControl: RatingControl!

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
    }
}
```

The problem is just with `photoImageView`. The other two outlets work fine.

Comment: Show `MealTableViewCell`

Comment: Make sure photoImageView is UIImageView IBOutlet..

Comment: @Sweeper Thanks. Please check my edited post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`[UITableViewCellContentView setImage:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance` indicates that the photoImageView outlet in your cell isn't really a UIImageView. For some reason, the photoImageView outlet seems to point to the cell's content view instead. My guess is that you have mistakenly connected the cell's contentview to this outlet instead of the imageview.

Also, it sometimes helps to do a "Clean" in XCode when errors such as this occur.

Comment: Can I try deleting the `photoImageView` and reconnect it?

Comment: Yes, absolutely

Answer (score 1):

Please check your IBOutlet for UIImageView is binded with your Cell.

Answer (score 1):

You problem is that you mistakenly connected the contentView of the `UITableViewCell` as an `UIImageView` named `photoImageView` which for sure has no member image that causes the crash

Answer (score 1):

**Hi i have explain my answer by the image, i hope this will help you**[image]